# javascript get value of a field in array oject

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, codeigniter

I everybody

in my codeigniter structure I have this array of object named $corsi

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
        [id] => 1
        [nome] => abcd
        [costo_mensile] => 5

    )

    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [nome] => efgh
        [costo_mensile] => 10
    )

)
```

I want to access this data with  javascript or a function javascript
its possibile ?
can i get for example the field "nome" ?

im try with

```
echo "('rif_corso', $corsi, '', 'onChange="run();" id="corsi"')
```

an in a script:

```
document.getElementById("corsi").value
```

can something help me ?
thanks a lot
riccardo

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you want to achieve: to read a server side data array (php) into a client side Javascript function, you need at least a form input or an ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

You can echo the whole js program somewhere into your html:

For example just before your closing `</body>` tag (if its possible with CodeIgniter) or some other script injection technique)

```
echo "<script>"
echo "var someVar = " . json_encode($phpVariable) . ";";
echo "console.log(someVar);";
echo "</script>";
echo "</body>";
```

> This is not the way of doing in some proper applications. Just for learning and understanding purposes.

Comment: is not my solution, i need to return this field